# Reading Category and Items From excel

Tags: java, excel, jxl

[image: My Excel File]

I wanna read category from excel file i cant read it by row number because items may vary. I am using `jxl`. I can take each cell type but Im getting Type `Label` for every cell

```
try {
        Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(
                "path to excel file"));
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(0);
        int colCount = sheet.getRows();
        for (int i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
            Cell cell = sheet.getCell(0, i);
            System.out.println(cell.getType() + " " + cell.getContents());
        }
    } catch (BiffException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I need to take Category names separately.

Comment: You are reading the first column. Why do you expect these cells to have varying types? It is possible that they all have type LABEL.

Comment: I need to get all category names

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, read column Quantity.

The first row contains a "Category" - retrieve and save (or whatever). Retrieve the numeric value from the cell, call it `sum`. Then, continue reading thw cells below. Retrieve the numeric value and subtract from `sum`. If `sum` is reduced to 0, increment the row, and repeat, unless you exceed the number of rows.

Comment: what about second row according to your idea... how can i define is it a item or category

Comment: I thought I had described this sufficiently well: Whenever `sum` is zero, the first column (0) contains a Category name. (What has "second row" got to do with it?)